# Resolver not resolving with angular firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, observable, google-cloud-firestore

I have added a resolver to get the user information from cloud firestore after the user logs in. However the resolver is not completing and the view is not being rendered.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreCollection,
  AngularFirestoreDocument
} from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import {AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class LoginUserResolve implements Resolve<any> {

  usersCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;
  users: any;
  userDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<any>;

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.usersCollection = this.afs.collection('users');
  }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    const email = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.email;
    console.log('Email: ', email);
    return this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('email', '==', email)).snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(proj => {
        const data: any = proj.payload.doc.data();
        data.id = proj.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      })));
  }
}
```

In the console log I see that the user's email is being logged, I don't see any logs from the component after that.

Comment: Have you tested the return if it's working (if it's really returning data whenu subscribe)?

Comment: Yes, I see the data when I add a log to the resolver. I see the document which the query returned

Comment: I ran into this exact same problem. Very frustrating. You cannot return observables that have not completed in the resolve method. If you were to add a take(1) after your map operator you would likely find it works. Unfortunately you now have a dead Observable thats been disconnected from Firestore. I am still trying to understand what the idiomatic way of using Firestore with a Resolver is. The most frustrating thing about this is that it fails silently.

Comment: Just adding the note. Try not streaming data for the resolver. Use `get()` instead of `snapshotChanges()`

Answer (score 1):

This is my workaround, I added a cached list for the firestore observable after it returns. and returning it as prommise on the next resolve calls. Although I truly think it should be fixed by the firebase team.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { CurrencyApiService, ICurrency } from '../services/currency-api.service';

@Injectable()
export class CurrencyResolver implements Resolve<ICurrency[]> {
    private list: ICurrency[] = [];
    constructor(
        private service: CurrencyApiService
    ) {}

    resolve(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): any {
        if (this.list.length > 0) {
            return new Promise(resolve => resolve(this.list));
        } else {
            const doc = this.service.filteredCurrencies.pipe(first()).toPromise();
            return doc.then(data => {
                this.list = data;
                return data;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Morilla Thaisa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2318353/morilla-thaisa) pretty much answers the question in the comments.

However, I thought I'd work out an example of how it would look like. I use this myself in my projects and works like a charm. Nevertheless, I think AngularFire team could improve on the returned objects, but that's not up to me and there's probably a workaround using RxJS operators, but I'm not sure.

**Routing Module**

```js
    {
      path: "about",
      component: AboutComponent,
      resolve: {
        about: AboutResolver
      }
    },
```

**Service**

```js
  getAll<T>(c: string): Observable<QuerySnapshot<T>> {
    this.increaseRequestsMade();
    return this.firestore.collection<T>(c).get();
  }
```

**Resolver**

```js
export class AboutResolver implements Resolve<QuerySnapshot<About>> {
  constructor(private aboutService: AboutService) {}

  resolve(
    _route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    _state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<QuerySnapshot<About>> | QuerySnapshot<About> {
    return this.aboutService.getAll<About>();
  }
}
```

**Component**

```js
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const aboutArray: About[] = this.route.snapshot.data.about.docs.map(d => d.data())
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it all within the resolver.
By providing an `Observable` that completes when the initial `Observable` itself sends its first value.

So instead of returning the data, I return the observable that will emit the values.
And to make sure at least 1 value was emitted, i use the `delayWhen` operator.
After the delayWhen is triggered, I make sure that the trigger-Observable gets completed by using `take(1)`

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Observable<Company>> {
        return of(this._companyService.company$).pipe(
            delayWhen(_ => this._companyService.company$.pipe(take(1))),
        );
    }
```

Note: the `CompanyService.company$` is a `ReplaySubject<Company>(1)`. Alternatively you could make sure you `pipe(shareReplay(1))`